# 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, вконтакте

бот VK , который раньше работал на vk_api (НЕ `VkBotLongPoll`) работал так:

```
if event.text == 'Текст сообщения':
    message('Тут был текст сообщения')
```

(P.s тут вызывается `DEF`)

После перехода на `VkBotLongPoll` стала появляться ошибка при получении сообщения - `'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'text'`

Основная часть кода (Весь код скидывать не буду, т.к слишком длинный и слишком много свистоперделок)

```
import random 
import requests
import vk_api
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
session = requests.Session()
vk_session = VkApi(token="Тут был токен.")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "Тут был айди группы.")
vk = vk_session.get_api()
keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
def message(text,noLinks=0):
    try:
        if event.from_chat: 
            vk.messages.send(
            random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9),
            chat_id = int(event.chat_id),
            message=str(text),
            dont_parse_links = noLinks
            )
        if event.from_user: 
            vk.messages.send(
            random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9),
            user_id=event.user_id,
            message=str(text),
            dont_parse_links = noLinks
            )
    except Exception:
        pass
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.text == 'test' or event.text == 'еуые':
            message('тест успешен')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `event.object['text']`